# Nested Form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I followed Episode 196 from Railcasts but seem that if i follow his it doesn't work quite yet, maybe cause the code is old or i just don't get rails.

Here I have 3 models

```
Customer        Book                Book_Manager
id              id                  id
first           description         customer_id
last            book_manager_id     visible
email
password
```

Here are my relationship

```
Book
    belongs_to :book_manager
    def customer
        book_manager.customer
    end
Customer
    has_many :book_managers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_managers
BookManager
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
```

The form is has follow

```
<%= form_for @bookmanager do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :books do |builder| %>
  <div>
    <%= builder.label :description %><br />
    <%= builder.text_area :description, :rows => 3 %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.label :visible %><br />  
    <%= f.text_field :visible %>  
  </div>  
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

If i comment out the line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
```

It show the description box, if however i place it there the box does disapear. Did i miss something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to pass a book object here. Try

```
<%= f.fields_for :books, Book.new do |builder| %>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, now i just need to set my create and update actions thank you very much